# Train Word/ Sentence Using Cognitive Services for handwritten form

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, handwriting-recognition

I need to train the data extracted from cognitive services. For example: I extract the data "Heri" using microsoft cognitive services but actual data in form is "Hari" . So, i need to train "e" to "a". Can i acheive it using cognitive services.

Answer (score 1):

The Computer Vision APIs doesn't allow customization, so you won't be able to train the model to achieve the desired results. However, check out Azure Form recognizer to determine whether it meets your requirements. With Form Recognizer, you can use prebuilt models or create [custom models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/concept-custom?tabs=fott), here's the custom model [quick start guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/label-tool) and [input requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/build-training-data-set).